# HTMLUNIT - Problem send Cookie for a request Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, cookies, htmlunit

I,m using HtmlUnit version 2.43.
When I click in the button a function javascript is called. This function create a link (new url) and this new page needs the Cookie (JSESSIONID) and after execute the result is show inside the a tag DIV.
But I tried everything and I don't can to do it work.
Please someone help me!

Code:
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
WebClientOptions options = client.getOptions();

```
    CookieManager cookieManager = client.getCookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiesEnabled(true);
    client.setCookieManager(cookieManager);

    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);

   HtmlTextInput inputCaptcha = paginaAfterConsultaIdentificadorCaptcha.querySelector("input[name='questionCL']");
   inputCaptcha.setValueAttribute("gr5w4");
   HtmlPage paginaInfLote = ((HtmlButtonInput) paginaAfterConsultaIdentificadorCaptcha.getElementById("botao_continuar")).click();
   client.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);

   System.out.println(paginaInfLote.asXml());

  <!-- I tried set to new cookie: -->

   Iterator<Cookie> index = cookies4.iterator();
   while (index.hasNext()) {
      vSessionId = index.next().toString();
       System.out.println(index.next());
       break;
    }
     String  vValueCookie = vSessionId.substring(11, vSessionId.indexOf(";"));

     Date dt = new Date();
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     c.setTime(dt);
     c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
     dt = c.getTime();

     Cookie cookie = new Cookie("www.licitacoes-e.com.br", "JSESSIONID", vValueCookie, "/",  dt, false);
     cookieManager.addCookie(cookie);
     client.setCookieManager(cookieManager);
  <!-- Fim set cookie -->
```

Comment: Cookie handling should be done automatically. Please open an issue on HtmlUnit-Github. And please use some tool like Charles web proxy to make sure there is any difference in the requests sent by HtmlUnit compared to reals browsers. If you can point to such an problem in a way i can reproduce that then there is a good chance that i can fix that.

Comment: First thanks for answer! I will install the Charles proxy and gonna show this result here.

Comment: Please use github issues  for the communication about all the details.